# заполнить table sqlite, Как мне заполнить таблицы subject и grade?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
students = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);"""

teachers = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teachers(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);"""

subject = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subject(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    ,name TEXT
    ,teachers_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,students_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,FOREIGN KEY(teachers_id) REFERENCES teachers(id)
    ,FOREIGN KEY(students_id) REFERENCES students(id)
    ,FOREIGN KEY(students_id) REFERENCES grades(id)
);"""


grade = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grade(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    ,grade INTEGER
    ,teachers_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,subjects_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,FOREIGN KEY(teachers_id) REFERENCES teachers(id)
    ,FOREIGN KEY(subjects_id) REFERENCES subject(id)
);"""
```

Comment: Сначала заполнить таблицы `teachers` и `subject`, потом `grade`, и последней - `subject`.